# Cloudflare HTTP 502 every X clicks

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, cloudflare, laravel-vapor

I wanted to give Laravel Vapor a try and deployed a simple project on a staging environment. Now I'm getting a HTTP 502 error every second or third request. With some URLs it seems to occur more often than with others but I can't find any problem with the app. It responds quickly and when I reload the URL the error is gone. It's reproducable though if I reload it another time or maybe a second time.

We are using the exact same app live on a "traditional" AWS setup and for dev/staging and VPS servers without ever getting any errors.

What I also don't get is why it's using Cloudflare with US IP addresses even though from the documentation I thought Amazon's CloudFront would be used. For various reasons we need the app to run on eu-central-1 with an IP address from that. Can I just get rid of Cloudflare somehow?

I'm using the vanity URL (something like https://snowy-cliff-XXXXXXX.vapor-farm-a1.com) provided by vapor, if that helps.

Thanks!

Comment: did you ever find a solution to the problem? Have been seeing this issue on and off with our deployment.